# Pendulum gyroscope

Tags: gravity, gyroscopes

Is there a gyroscope (a device that enables orientation detection) built with only a pendulum and a gimbal?

If I understand the terminology, this device would not use conservation of angular momentum but gravity?

Comment: You mean a Foucault pendulum? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum. Sure, it's just not used much (if at all) as a "gyroscope" because it's not particularly sensitive. If you use a tuning fork instead of a pendulum, then you get a technically useful vibrational gyroscope.

Comment: @CuriousOne not really. i was thinking about something like this: http://www.technitoys.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/IMG_8516.jpg Although now i realize that inertia or side forces would make a device like this useless

Comment: That looks more like a cardan joint to me. It's not how one would build a technical gyroscope for all I can tell.